# Why does QueueClient RegisterSessionHandler stop working?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-servicebus-queues

We use Session-Queues in Azure Service Bus (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.1.0) with ASP.NET Core (2.1).

We created a HostedService (implementing the IHostedService Interface and added it to the hosted services in the ConfigureService-Method in Startup).

In the Hosted Service we have the following code:

```
this.client = new QueueClient(
    this.configuration.ServiceBusConnectionString,
    this.configuration.SessionBasedQueueName,
    ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

this.client.RegisterSessionHandler(
    async (
        session,
        message,
        _) =>
    {
        try
        {
            // handle the message here

            await session.CompleteAsync(
                message
                    .SystemProperties
                    .LockToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!session.IsClosedOrClosing)
            {
                await session.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
    },
    new SessionHandlerOptions(x =>
    {
        // log the exception here

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    })
    {
        AutoComplete = false,
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 1
    });

return Task.CompletedTask;
```

Now, when the code gets executed, it works for some time meaning that messages get handled. But after some time (can take an hour, can take only two minutes) it suddenly stops but there are still messages in the queue.
Without an exception the lambda function doesn't get called anymore.

What did we do wrong and how can we fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's been a while, but I'm seeing similar behavior here. Do you remember what the issue was? Was it because you were only handling a single concurrent session, and letting the MessageWaitTimeout default to 1(?) minute without explicitly calling session.Close()?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles upon this question, the problem might be this:

Since you are using a session-enabled queue, the number of sessions you write to the queue must match the number of MaxConcurrentSessions - if you want to consume them continously.

Otherwise the MessageWaitTimeout is the time it will run idle, after the timeout it will find a new session id to consume.

Say you are using modulus (eg productId % 100) for calculating the session id when writing to the queue. The example will generate 100 different session ids. Hence you "have" to set MaxConcurrentSessions to 100.

Comment: Seems a bit sad that "idle" time actually .. The tips about the "modulus 100" made my day, thanks